# Login using facebook in android app

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate facebook with my android app. I have implemented the code provided by "developers.facebook.com" but I am getting an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" .I have tried all the possible solutions but none is working.I have also replaced android-support-v4.jar by android-support-v4.jar of facebook-sdk but still getting the same error. Code is-

```
package com.example.facebooklogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
     Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }
      }
    });
  }
 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

}
```

Logcat:

```
05-23 03:10:53.172: W/dalvikvm(1578): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
05-23 03:10:53.172: W/dalvikvm(1578): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
05-23 03:10:53.182: I/dalvikvm(1578): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
05-23 03:10:53.182: W/dalvikvm(1578): VFY: unable to resolve static method 216: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
05-23 03:10:53.182: D/dalvikvm(1578): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
05-23 03:10:53.492: D/AndroidRuntime(1578): Shutting down VM
05-23 03:10:53.492: W/dalvikvm(1578): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a63b90)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): Process: com.example.facebooklogin, PID: 1578
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1327)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:790)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:890)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:830)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.example.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-23 03:10:53.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Anushka, can send you full source code if you need!!!

Comment: @pratik-Thank you but I have found the solution.My problem is resolved now.

Comment: its ok anushka, no worries, should v b in touch?

Comment: Anushka, not got yr reply dear???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// first class for login**

```
public class LoginScreen  extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{


    FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);



        MainFragment mainFrag=new MainFragment();
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,mainFrag, "userlogin");
        transaction.commit();



    }


}
```

**// xml for main class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

   >





  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:id="@+id/MyFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    </FrameLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

**// Main Fragment.java**

```
package com.example.freejeetoproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.util.Arrays;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
     //private GraphUser user;
     Context context;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainlogin, container, false);
        Button authButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        ((LoginButton) authButton).setFragment(this);
       // read permission for email
        ((LoginButton) authButton).setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));





        return view;
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

        }
    };



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {


            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                 // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                      //  profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                        Log.e("name",user.getName());

                        String email=(String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");

                        Log.e("email",email);



                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // Handle errors, will do so later.
                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    } 



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }*/
        uiHelper.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//      if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e("on","activityResult");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        Log.e("on","pause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
        Log.e("on","destroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.e("on","SaveInstaneState");
    }
}
```

**// xml for main Fragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked checkboxes for required libraries just like

https://plus.google.com/photos/+AndreasSt%C3%BCtz/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162?pid=5878509268379848162&oid=%2BAndreasSt%C3%BCtz

and secondly check

replace android-support-v4.jar in lib> with which is present in facebook sdk

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev- R u talking about Android Private libraries and Android Dependencies in order and export tab of java build path.

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev-Yes I have.

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev- Does version of facebook sdk matters?

Comment: replace `android-support-v4.jar` in `lib>` with which is present in `facebook sdk`